# How to make web service for insert image to server with Spring?

Tags: java, android, spring, web-services

I want to learn about insert image to server with android studio and back-end using Spring, some tutorial on google its doesn't work. by the way i tried on android Nougat, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by Insert Image on Server? Android studio and Spring are two different things. Android Studio is an IDE used for developing android apps and Spring is a framework.
Be very clear with your questions first then only you will get useful contents, even on google too. I am hoping that you need a webservice which you will call from android app and upload an image on server?

Comment: My back-end using Spring in Java (Netbean), i want to upload Image from android